# NSubstitute mock extension method

Tags: c#, random, mocking, nsubstitute

I want to do mock extension method, but it does not work. How can this be done?

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> NextInt32s(this System.Random random, int neededValuesNumber, int minInclusive, int maxExclusive)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

```
[Fact]
public void Select()
{
    var randomizer = Substitute.For<DefaultRandom>();
    randomizer.NextInt32s(3, 1, 10).Returns(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't mock a extension method with free mocking frameworks. Because extension methods are just static methods, and you can't mock a static method with free mocking frameworks. TypeMock does this I think(but that's beyond the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSubstitute can not mock extension methods as per Sriram's comment, but you can still pass a mocked argument to an extension method.

In this case, the `Random` class has virtual methods, so we can mock that directly with NSubstitute and other DynamicProxy-based mocking tools. (For NSubstitute in particular we need to be very careful mocking classes. Please read the warning in [the documentation](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/).)

```
public static class RandomExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<int> NextInt32s(this System.Random random, int neededValuesNumber, int minInclusive, int maxExclusive) { /* ... */ }
}
public class RandomExtensionsTests {
    [Test]
    public void Select()
    {
        const int min = 0, max = 10;
        var randomizer = Substitute.For<Random>();
        randomizer.Next(min, max).Returns(1, 2, 3);

        var result = randomizer.NextInt32s(3, 0, 10).ToArray();

        Assert.AreEqual(new[] {1, 2, 3}, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the mock does not return {1,2,3} but goes into the code /* ... */. See [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a27d3bd572d8abdaf4770805b93eefdb)

Comment: @Damian It only works if the extension method calls the mocked object. In the gist, `NextInt32s()` would need to call `random.Next(minInclusive, maxInclusive)`.

Comment: In the dotnet framework Random.Next(min, max) returns an int, not an array of int.
Warning new to C#!

Comment: Ah, ok if you're new to C# NSubstitute might confuse you as it (mis)uses C# syntax in interesting/odd ways. If you implement `NextInt32()` as `for (var i=0; i<neededValuesNumber; i++) yield return random.Next(minInclusive, maxInclusive);` I think the test will pass, but you may need to start a new question to tackle the specific problem/s you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi David! This is a different question but can NSubstitute mock a regular static method too? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Jenix: no it can't, please see Sriram's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693698/nsubstitute-mock-extension-method/28708195?noredirect=1#comment45678624_28693698

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mock if you create an interface such as `IRandom` and extend the interface instead of the actual implementation. Then you should be able mock the interface in your test class.

```
public interface IRandom
{   
}

public class Random : IRandom
{     
}

public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static string NextInt32s(
        this IRandom random, 
        int neededValuesNumber, 
        int minInclusive, 
        int maxExclusive)
    {
    }
}
```

In your test class add:

```
IRandom randomizer = Substitute.For<IRandom>();
var result = randomizer.NextInt32s(3,0,10);
```

By this process you are just mocking the interface not the actual class.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to other answers, here is how I got round it.

Imagine there is an interface `IDoStuff` and there is a library that extends `IDoStuff`. You have a class `MyClass` that implements `IDoStuff` and somewhere someone uses the extension method against the interface. It looks like this;

```
using System;

interface IDoStuff
{
    string SayHello();
}

class MyClass : IDoStuff
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

// somewhere someone wrote an extension method for IDoStuff

static class DoStuffExtensions
{
    static string SayHelloToBob(this IDoStuff other)
    {
        return other.SayHello() + " Bob";
    }
}

class UserOfIDoStuff
{
    void UseIDoStuff(IDoStuff incoming)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(incoming.SayHelloToBob());
    }
}
```

You want to mock `IDoStuff` but you cannot mock the extension method `SayHelloToBob`. What you can do is to create another interface that implements `IDoStuff` but also includes `SayHelloToBob`.

```
interface IDoStuffWithExtensions : IDoStuff
{
    string SayHelloToBob();
}

class MyClass : IDoStuffWithExtensions
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    // Wrap / internalise the extension method
    public string SayHelloToBob()
    {
        return DoStuffExtensions.SayHelloToBob(this);
    }
}

class UserOfIDoStuff
{
    void UseIDoStuff(IDoStuffWithExtensions incoming)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(incoming.SayHelloToBob());
    }
}
```

Now you can happily mock `IDoStuffWithExtensions`.

Comment: Interesting approach. But it only works if you change all your tested code to use the interface with extensions. Otherwise, you can successfully create a substitute, but it still won't be called later because the original interface extension methods apply. And that totally goes against using extension methods in the first place. So this won't work for real applications.

Answer (score -4):

According to SOLID principle dependence inversion defines that lower level model should not be depended high level model but depended on abstract like interface and mocking concept is mainly used to mock interface so that low level model is not tested.

Comment: Yes, but if I define interface for DefaultRandom and mock him, then it doesn't see extension method NextInt32s. How can I do?