# NSubstitute mocking Mongo IFindFluent does not work

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I was doing dome unit tests around my repository, until I got a strange error. Searched around to see if I was not making known mistakes, I could simplify it and notice that I am getting the same error.
Looks like I cannot mock IFindFluent interface properly, and I would like to know what I am doing wrong. This test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var ff = Substitute.For<IFindFluent<string, string>>();
        ff.FirstOrDefaultAsync().Returns("asd");
    }
```

is returning this error message:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException :
>   Can not return value of type Task`1 for IDisposable.Dispose (expected
>   type Void).
>
> Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for
>   example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)), and that you are not
>   configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid
>   this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).
>
> If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that
>   the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member. Return
>   values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.
>
> Correct use:
>       mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);
>
> Potentially problematic use:
>       mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub()); Instead try:
>       var returnValue = ConfigOtherSub();
>       mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);
>
> at
>   NSubstitute.Core.ConfigureCall.CheckResultIsCompatibleWithCall(IReturn
>   valueToReturn, ICallSpecification spec)    at
>   NSubstitute.Core.ConfigureCall.SetResultForLastCall(IReturn
>   valueToReturn, MatchArgs matchArgs)    at
>   NSubstitute.Core.SubstitutionContext.LastCallShouldReturn(IReturn
>   value, MatchArgs matchArgs)    at
>   CorporateActions.Tests.Persistence.RepositoryTests.Test()

I've searched around, but most common mistakes about it does not fit with this simple implementation. Any thoughts why does this not work?

Comment: Can you please post the signature of `IFindFluent.FirstOrDefaultAsync`? Or is it an extension method?

Comment: As CodeFuller noted on answer below, it is an extension method. Did not know that I could not mock it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FirstOrDefaultAsync` is an extension method for `IFindFluent<TDocument, TProjection>`. Unfortunately, NSubstitute [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693698/nsubstitute-mock-extension-method) mocking of extension methods.

However it does not mean you can't develop proper UT in this case. Extension methods for interfaces eventually call some method(s) of those interfaces. So the common workaround for this problem is to check what interface methods are actually called and mock them, instead of mocking whole extension method.

`IFindFluentExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` is [defined as](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/IFindFluentExtensions.cs):

```
public static Task<TProjection> FirstOrDefaultAsync<TDocument, TProjection>(this IFindFluent<TDocument, TProjection> find, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    Ensure.IsNotNull(find, nameof(find));

    return IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(find.Limit(1), cancellationToken);
}
```

Now you see that you should mock `IFindFluent<TDocument, TProjection>.Limit(int? limit)` method and dig into `IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` extension method.

`IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync` is [defined as](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/IAsyncCursorSource.cs):

```
public static async Task<TDocument> FirstOrDefaultAsync<TDocument>(this IAsyncCursorSource<TDocument> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (var cursor = await source.ToCursorAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        return await cursor.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

So you need to mock `IAsyncCursorSource<TDocument>.ToCursorAsync()` and check `IAsyncCursorExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` extension method.

`IAsyncCursorExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` is [defined as](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/IAsyncCursor.cs):

```
public static async Task<TDocument> FirstOrDefaultAsync<TDocument>(this IAsyncCursor<TDocument> cursor, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (cursor)
    {
        var batch = await GetFirstBatchAsync(cursor, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return batch.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

So the last method to analyze is `IAsyncCursorExtensions.GetFirstBatchAsync()`, which is [defined as](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/IAsyncCursor.cs):

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<TDocument>> GetFirstBatchAsync<TDocument>(IAsyncCursor<TDocument> cursor, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (await cursor.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        return cursor.Current;
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<TDocument>();
    }
}
```

Here we see that we should also mock `IAsyncCursor.MoveNextAsync()` and `IAsyncCursor.Current`.

Here is the test method that mocks all discovered calls:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var cursorMock = Substitute.For<IAsyncCursor<string>>();
    cursorMock.MoveNextAsync().Returns(Task.FromResult(true), Task.FromResult(false));
    cursorMock.Current.Returns(new[] { "asd" });

    var ff = Substitute.For<IFindFluent<string, string>>();
    ff.ToCursorAsync().Returns(Task.FromResult(cursorMock));
    ff.Limit(1).Returns(ff);

    var result = ff.FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
    Assert.AreEqual("asd", result);
}
```

Comment: An awesome explanation and a really complete answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but I think it is also worth mentioning the risk of this approach -- this test will be very brittle if any of the extension implementations change (unless this is what we're trying to test for?). It might be worth wrapping this function behind a testable interface the author has full control over and can be confident mocking, and then test the actual implementation in a more realistic scenario (i.e. with no mocking).