# How to mock IConfiguration Get<Foo>() extension method with NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-core-webapi, nsubstitute

I am developing Asp.net Core 6 Web Api project.

I have appsettings:

```
"MainSection": {
   "FirstSubsection":{
         "SomeKey": "someValue"
    },
    "SecondSubSection": {
         SomeKey: "somevalue"
    }
```

In the code I get "somevalue" through a typed model Foo in the following way:

```
configuration
.GetSection("MainSection")
.GetSection("SecondSection")
.Get<Foo>();
```

Foo is a typed class. .Get() method comes from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration ConfigurationBuilder.

**How do I mock Get() method in unit test using NSubstitute?**

When I try to mock it like this, I get the error: Can not return value of type Foo for IDisposable.Dispose (expected type void).

```
var section = Substitute.For<IConfigurationSection>();
section.Get<Foo>().Returns(new Foo(){ SomeProperty = "aa"});
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693698/nsubstitute-mock-extension-method) NSubstitute can not mock extension methods.

I tried setting:

```
section.Key.Returns("SomeKey");
section.Value.Returns("someValue");
```

But the Get() method still returns null.

How can I mock it?

**Edit: I need a solution similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189413/7654641), tried a million times, but I just can't get it to work with NSubstitute.**

Comment: Check the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/64795010/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi, yes, I saw this answer, but I really want to make it like a clean unit test. I don't want to use In-Memory providers. I found a solution for Moq, but I just can't get it to work for NSubstitute. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189413/7654641